# pthread_create not found, on "make" of OSRM-Project

Tags: linux, compilation, pthreads, openstreetmap, osrm

I am trying to set up OSRM-project on my linux server, however am experiencing issues while doing so. I have the latest versions of the dependencies, and have also installed and setup pthreads:
pecl pthread install

then adding it to php, and recompiling php.

Below is the information:

Centos 6 64bit, trying to set up OSRM-Project.

downloading soure, then:

```
cd osrm-backend
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake -D STXXL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/include/stxxl.h ..
make
```

Build fails on make:

> Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following
>   output: Change Dir:
>   /var/www/html/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTryCompileExec3544628293/fast"
>   /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3544628293.dir/build.make
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3544628293.dir/build gmake[1]: Entering
>   directory `/var/www/html/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report
>   /var/www/html/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
>   Building C object
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3544628293.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
>   /usr/local/bin/cc    -o
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3544628293.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c
>   /var/www/html/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
>   Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3544628293 /usr/local/bin/cmake
>   -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3544628293.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
>   /usr/local/bin/cc
>
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3544628293.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o
>   cmTryCompileExec3544628293 -rdynamic
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3544628293.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In
>   function`main': CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference
>   to `pthread_create' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3544628293] Error 1 gmake[1]: Leaving
>   directory`/var/www/html/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec3544628293/fast] Error 2
>
> File
>   /var/www/html/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
>   /* */
>   #include
>
> int main(int argc, char** argv) {   (void)argv;
>   #ifndef pthread_create   return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
>   #else   (void)argc;   return 0;
>   #endif }
>
> Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads
>   failed with the following output: Change Dir:
>   /var/www/html/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTryCompileExec4016411170/fast"
>   /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4016411170.dir/build.make
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4016411170.dir/build gmake[1]: Entering
>   directory `/var/www/html/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report
>   /var/www/html/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
>   Building C object
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4016411170.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
>   /usr/local/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4016411170.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c
>   /usr/local/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c Linking C
>   executable cmTryCompileExec4016411170 /usr/local/bin/cmake -E
>   cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4016411170.dir/link.txt
>   --verbose=1 /usr/local/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4016411170.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o
>   cmTryCompileExec4016411170 -rdynamic -lpthreads
>   /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld:
>   cannot find -lpthreads collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec4016411170] Error 1 gmake[1]: Leaving
>   directory`/var/www/html/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Comment: `cannot find -lpthreads` this seems the issue. can you please check `PATH` variable?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-lpthread`, as the library is call `libpthread.so`.

Comment: It is `pthread`, not `pthreads`. Use `-pthread` instead.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, that is indeed the issue, but checking PATH won't help find libraries, and as the other comments say there's no point checking any paths because the library name is imply wrong.

Comment: @JonathanWakely right you are. thanks. :-)

Comment: So I've tried the following:
cmake -D STXXL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/include/stxxl.h -pthread ..

which resulted in the following:

-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE

Comment: Trying to make the build. results in the same error as before

Comment: why would you need to create the parent directories?  Your already at the current directory and the call to mkdir is not indicating a full path?